# TypeScript generics for common reducer typing

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a common reducer function to be shared.
I want it to be typed properly.
I came up with this:

```
export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends { [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }> {
  invalidRows: T;
}

interface AddPayload<S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>> {
  cell: InvalidCell;
  screenKey: keyof S['invalidRows'];
}

const addInvalidCell = <S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>>(
  state: S, 
  { cell, screenKey }: AddPayload<S>
) => {
  const rows = state.invalidRows[screenKey];
  const index = R.findIndex((item) => item.id === cell.id, rows);

  ...
};
```

But I'm getting error `Type 'S["invalidRows"]' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [K in keyof S["invalidRows"]]: InvalidCell[]; }'.`
Can someone please explain me how `S['invalidRows']` which ultimately is `{ [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }` is not assignable there?

---

**Appendix:**

With this type

```
type RowsExtend<T> = Record<keyof T, InvalidCell[]>;
export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends RowsExtend<T> = any> {
  invalidRows: RowsExtend<T>;
}
```

I now get an error `TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.` here:

```
const reducer = createReducer(
  on(ImportScreenActions.addInvalidEntityRowImportScreen, addInvalidCell),
  ...
);
```

Types from `@ngrx`:

```
export declare type ActionCreator<T extends string = string, C extends Creator = Creator> = C & TypedAction<T>;
export declare type ActionType<A> = A extends ActionCreator<infer T, infer C> ? ReturnType<C> & {
    type: T;
} : never;
export interface OnReducer<S, C extends ActionCreator[]> {
    (state: S, action: ActionType<C[number]>): S;
}
export declare function on<C1 extends ActionCreator, S>(creator1: C1, reducer: OnReducer<S, [C1]>): On<S>;
```

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Comment: [Here you go](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSSQDdMAbBAEwGFhTS4BvAWACg5EKAuOAZximQBzANyt2PYETQIYAT258BSEawC+rVqEixEKNFlxwA6jIAWhEuQoAlCAHceAHgAqcUKiQUejOAG0A0rpwANbAshDocM4AutwWZJQ0dL7RcKoAfIxiupaUtg7czqIs6iysyKgYOHgAghQUAAqYsqQQmBSOAMpuIB5exmbxVvlOnb4A5Mi5NvY849HpmcxscLh0ccQJ1LSkxeLYUMDASP5h3KHhkWOTm8Oz88WlrNgQSHxw7RRDiTtwALxwLo9PreEwwcy3PKzLoTKZbEbzRYACmyfEwqG4nQANHBsgxVjscTwDkcTmE0tw6o1mq12l10qwAJT-JbZF5veBQWb-XgwdHAAB0cLuDl8xMOx1Osmie1Wr3eyAooB5XIcAvQisISpASKRMmAAFtmX9MvqDUKKP8-gC1qQLTjVTxGY9hEA)

Comment: Do you expect `S` to be recursive type?

Comment: Please provide some examples with data

Comment: No, `S` refers to type of State (not recursive).
`interface MyState extends WithInvalidRows<InvalidRowsScreen> { ... }`

`interface InvalidRowsScreen {
  foo: InvalidCell[];
  bar: InvalidCell[];
  baz: InvalidCell[];
  ...
}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the closed [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) where typescript team have improved/added some of the features of `indexed access type` in a number of ways.

Some of the features that I like to mention here which relates to the current behavior.

> When an indexed access `T[K]` occurs on the source side of a type relationship, it resolves to a union type of the properties selected by `T[K]`, but when it occurs on the target side of a type relationship, it now resolves to an intersection type of the properties selected by `T[K]`. Previously, the target side would resolve to a union type as well, which is unsound.

> Given a type variable `T` with a constraint `C`, when an indexed access `T[K]` occurs on the target side of a type relationship, index signatures in `C` are now ignored. This is because a type argument for `T` isn't actually required to have an index signature, it is just required to have properties with matching types.

> In general, the constraint `Record<string, XXX>` doesn't actually ensure that an argument has a string index signature, it merely ensures that the properties of the argument are assignable to type `XXX`.

In your case,

```
export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends { [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }> {
  invalidRows: T;
}
interface AddPayload<S extends WithInvalidRows<S["invalidRows"]>> {
    cell: InvalidCell;
    screenKey: keyof S["invalidRows"];
}
```

`S["invalidRows"]` takes the type of invalidRows key of generic `T`,

```
S['invalidRows'] = T
```

Here we didn't know the index signature of `T` so `S['invalidRows']` is not able to understand that it is an index type.

So, the only solution that I can think of is to give the index signature of generic `T`. Since it is an interface we cannot do typecast so, therefore, we have to give the type of `invalidRows` key  same as constraint type.

```
type RowsExtend<T> = Record<keyof T, InvalidCell[]>;
export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends RowsExtend<T>> {
    invalidRows: RowsExtend<T>;
}
```

**Full code with examples:**

```
export interface InvalidCell {
    id: string;
    severity?: string;
}

type RowsExtend<T> = Record<keyof T, InvalidCell[]>;
export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends RowsExtend<T>> {
    invalidRows: RowsExtend<T>;
}

interface AddPayload<S extends WithInvalidRows<S["invalidRows"]>> {
    cell: InvalidCell;
    screenKey: keyof S["invalidRows"];
}

interface MyState extends WithInvalidRows<InvalidRowsScreen> {
    // more states
}

interface InvalidRowsScreen {
    foo: InvalidCell[];
    bar: InvalidCell[];
    baz: InvalidCell[];
}
const addInvalidCell = <S extends WithInvalidRows<S["invalidRows"]>>(
    state: S,
    { cell, screenKey }: AddPayload<S>
) => {
    const rows = state.invalidRows[screenKey];
    const index = rows.findIndex(item => item.id === cell.id, rows);
};

const someState: MyState = {
    invalidRows: {
        foo: [{ id: "22" }],
        bar: [{ id: "123" }],
        baz: [{ id: "634" }],
    },
    // some more states
};

addInvalidCell(someState, {
    cell: { id: "123" },
    screenKey: "foo",
});

addInvalidCell(someState, {
    cell: { id: "123" },
    screenKey: "invalid",
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please check the Appendix on my question?

Comment: What is the return type of `addInvalidCell` function? It's an array but array of what type?

Comment: Maybe this [discussion](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35156) might get help

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult to pinpoint why it gives that error. While it was kind of obvious it had to do with the "recursive" generic type, e.g. `S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>`, getting more details was tricky. I went with the "let me play around with it and try some things out" approach to maybe shed some light.

---

A first working modification of your code is this:

```js
interface InvalidCell {
    id: number;
}

export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends { [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }> {
    invalidRows: T;
}

interface AddPayload<R extends { [K in keyof R]: InvalidCell[] }> {
    cell: InvalidCell;
    screenKey: keyof R;
}

const addInvalidCell = <
    R extends { [K in keyof R]: InvalidCell[] },
    S extends WithInvalidRows<R>
>(
    state: S,
    { cell, screenKey }: AddPayload<R>
) => {
    const rows = state.invalidRows[screenKey];
    const id: number = rows[0].id;
};

interface MyState extends WithInvalidRows<InvalidRowsScreen> {
    someExtraState: string;
}

interface InvalidRowsScreen {
    foo: InvalidCell[];
    bar: InvalidCell[];
    baz: InvalidCell[];
}

const myState: MyState = null!;
const invalidRows: InvalidRowsScreen = myState.invalidRows;
const someExtraState: string = myState.someExtraState

// Valid
addInvalidCell(myState, {
    cell: { id: 123 },
    screenKey: 'foo',
});
// Error that myState misses the field 'invalid'
addInvalidCell(myState, {
    cell: { id: 123 },
    screenKey: 'invalid',
});
```

I did have to change what the generic parameter of `AddPayload` represents and add this same generic parameter to `addInvalidCell`. TypeScript can still interfere both types, as seen in the example function calls above.

---

Then after some more fiddling, the error surprisingly disappears when I changed the `WithInvalidRows` just a bit:

```js
interface InvalidCell {
    id: number;
}

export interface WithInvalidRows<T extends { [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }> {
    invalidRows: { [key in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }; // originally just `T`
}

interface AddPayload<S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>> {
    cell: InvalidCell;
    screenKey: keyof S['invalidRows'];
}

const addInvalidCell = <S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>>(
    state: S,
    { cell, screenKey }: AddPayload<S>
) => {
    const rows = state.invalidRows[screenKey];
    const id: number = rows[0].id;
};

interface MyState extends WithInvalidRows<InvalidRowsScreen> {
    someExtraState: string;
}

interface InvalidRowsScreen {
    foo: InvalidCell[];
    bar: InvalidCell[];
    baz: InvalidCell[];
}

const myState: MyState = null!;

// Valid
addInvalidCell(myState, {
    cell: { id: 123 },
    screenKey: 'foo',
});
addInvalidCell(myState, {
    cell: { id: 123 },
    screenKey: 'invalid', // Error that 'invalid' is not assignable to `keyof InvalidRowsScreen`
});
```

I'd be lying if I said that I know exactly why this fixes it. Somehow being extra verbose there makes TypeScript handle the "recursive generic" better.

I'd say it's because `S extends WithInvalidRows<S['invalidRows']>` tries to read the `invalidRows: T` field which it tries to read from the (passed) generic parameter which is actually `S['invalidRows']`, and somehow TypeScript can't compute that (still `S`-validation) type loop.

By using `invalidRows: { [key in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }`, it's more like telling TypeScript "that generic parameter `T`? can be whatever you want", which allows `S` to pass the type validation. And since `S` is valid, `keyof T` which is `keyof S['invalidRows']` can just be calculated fine.

A similar example that stops your error from making `S['invalidRows']` error:

```js
interface WithInvalidRowsKeys<K extends keyof any> {
    invalidRows: { [key in K]: InvalidCell[] };
}

export type WithInvalidRows<T extends { [K in keyof T]: InvalidCell[] }> = WithInvalidRowsKeys<keyof T>;
```

Just like the previous solution, we're not directly making `invalidRows: T` part of verification of `WithInvalidRows`. `T` gets type checked, **then** `keyof T` is used to define `WithInvalidRows`'s fields.

But this is all just my theory based on what did and didn't work.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your answer, even though I'd need to read it several times more to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @PavelStaselun Like I said, I'm not very sure myself, it's quite a weird situation. Now that I had some time to think about it, it might be better to explain it as `invalidRows: T` becoming part of the type checking/validation of `WithInvalidRows<T>`, while `invalidRows: { ... }` isn't really used for the validation, but only to fill out the type afterwards. Then again, still just a likely theory I thought of.

Comment: @PavelStaselun Also don't forget to mark this answer as the solution, assuming nobody comes up with a better answer.

Comment: Sorry, I marked the other answer as correct as it give an actual explanation on what is going on.